# How to extract data in sentiment analysis due to which the sentiment is calculated? (Words which are responsible for sentiment)

Tags: python, django, sentiment-analysis

For example: I love icecreame -----> here due to love word the data becomes positive sentiment.
In the same way how to find the exact words which are responsible for the resulting sentiment.
I have written some basic code in Python (django framework) related to sentiment analysis as following:

```
data="Love the new update. It's super fast!"
sid_obj=SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
sentiment_dict=sid_obj.polarity_scores(data)
negative=sentiment_dict['neg']
neutral=sentiment_dict['neu']
positive=sentiment_dict['pos']
compound=sentiment_dict['compound']
if sentiment_dict['compound']>=0.05:
 overall_sentiment='Positive'
elif sentiment_dict['compound'] <= -0.05:
 overall_sentiment='Negative'
else:
 overall_sentiment='Neutral'
```

Note: I have imported the packages which are required for the execution of above code and it works.

Can anyone pleas help me in adding the important code which extracts the words responsible for the resulting sentiment?

Comment: Which library are you using for this?

Comment: from vaderSentiment.vaderSentiment import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer

Comment: When you say "extracts the words responsible for the resulting sentiment" are you looking for the valence score of each word?

Comment: not exactly, but due to which word the sentiment is calculated means which word is having high possibility for the result